# This product is currently out of stock. Magento 1.9.4

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing issues while creating sales order programmatically.

Here is my code :-

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

$store = Mage::app()->getStore();
$website = Mage::app()->getWebsite();

//Create sales quote object
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($store->getStoreId());

//Customer information
$customerEmail = "diegodelgado900@msn.com";
$customerFirstname = "Diego"; 
$customerLastname = "Delgado";

$billingAddress = array(
    'customer_address_id' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'firstname' => $customerFirstname,
    'middlename' => '',
    'lastname' => $customerLastname,
    'suffix' => '',
    'company' => '', 
    'street' => array(
        '0' => '13877 sw 151 lane'),
    'city' => 'Miami',
    'country_id' => 'US', // country code
    'region' => 'Miami',
    'region_id' => '2',
    'postcode' => '33186',
    'telephone' => '999-888-0000',
    'fax' => '',
    'save_in_address_book' => 1
);

$shippingAddress = array(
    'customer_address_id' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'firstname' => $customerFirstname,
    'middlename' => '',
    'lastname' => $customerLastname,
    'suffix' => '',
    'company' => '', 
    'street' => array(
        '0' => '13877 sw 151 lane'),
    'city' => 'Miami',
    'country_id' => 'US', // country code
    'region' => 'Miami',
    'region_id' => '2',
    'postcode' => '33186',
    'telephone' => '999-888-0000',
    'fax' => '',
    'save_in_address_book' => 1
);

//Check whether the customer already registered or not
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->setWebsiteId($website->getId())->loadByEmail($customerEmail);

if (!$customer->getId()) {

    //Create the new customer account if not registered
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer'); 
    $customer->setWebsiteId($website->getId())
             ->setStore($store)
             ->setFirstname($customerFirstname)
             ->setLastname($customerLastname)
             ->setEmail($customerEmail);

    try {
        $password = $customer->generatePassword(); 
        $customer->setPassword($password);

        //Set the customer as confirmed
        $customer->setForceConfirmed(true);
        $customer->save();

        $customer->setConfirmation(null);
        $customer->save();

        //Set customer address
        $customerId = $customer->getId(); 
        $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address'); 
        $customAddress->setData($billingAddress)
                      ->setCustomerId($customerId)
                      ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
                      ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
                      ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

        //Save customer address
        $customAddress->save();

        //Send new account email to customer
        $storeId = $customer->getSendemailStoreId();
        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail('registered', '', $storeId);

        //Set password remainder email if the password is auto generated by magento
        $customer->sendPasswordReminderEmail();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    } 
}

//Assign the customer to quote
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);

//Set currency for the quote
$quote->setCurrency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode());

$productIds = array(14470,1); //array('product_id' => 'qty')

//Add products to quote
foreach($productIds as $productId => $qty) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
}

//Add billing address to quote
$billingAddressData = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($billingAddress);

//Add shipping address to quote
$shippingAddressData = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($shippingAddress);

//Collect shipping rates on quote
$shippingAddressData->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates();

//Set shipping method and payment method on the quote
$shippingAddressData->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')->setPaymentMethod('free'); //Shipping is flatrate for this example

//Set payment method for the quote
$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'free')); //Payment is check and money order for this example

try {
    //Collect totals & save quote
    $quote->collectTotals()->save();

    //Create order from quote
    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
    $service->submitAll();
    $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();

    echo 'Order Id: ' .$increment_id. ' has been successfully created.';

} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::logException($e);
}
```

Error :-

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message
>   'This product is currently out of stock.' in
>   /home/domain/public_html/app/Mage.php:598 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1022):
>   Mage::throwException('This product is...') #1
>   /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(1046):
>   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addProductAdvanced(Object(Anowave_Ec_Model_Product),
>   1, 'full') #2 /home/domain/public_html/test.php(116):
>   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addProduct(Object(Anowave_Ec_Model_Product),
>   1) #3 {main} thrown in /home/domain/public_html/app/Mage.php on line
>   598

[image: Here is stock of product]

This error comes up also when i change the products.

Also i have clear the cache and re-index all tried, But no luck.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Its looked like your product is `Out Of Stock` check the product in admin and assign some quantity and make the stock status to `in stock`.

[image]

Comment: It is in stock, please see the image in original question that show stock quantity.

Comment: @BalkishanNatani, yes that is fine you have the stock quantity but can you check the stock status is `in-stock` or `out of stock`

Comment: I checked ...its in stock here...is there is any other way to generate sales order?

Comment: @BalkishanNatani, Yes you can do by allowing backorder.
I am adding screen for allowing backorder

Comment: see I have added the backorder screen.

Comment: Not working for me...Also i sometimes shows

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'The requested Payment Method is not available.' in /home/domain/public_html/app/Mage.php:598 Stack trace: #0 /home/domain/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Payment.php(153): Mage::throwException('The requested P...') #1 /home/domain/public_html/test.php(143): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment->importData(Array) #2 {main} thrown in /home/domain/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 598

Although i have enable free payment methods in backend.